# Do you split MVC even if the differences are less than 10%?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, architecture, uiviewcontroller, screen

Some of my UIViewControllers consist of several screens. I merged such each MVCs within one xib because the differences in screens were about 10% only (some different labels and buttons). The thing is I need to show concrete screen when pushing concrete UIViewController on screen. So, I have methods like "show screen1 and hide screen2" and "show screen2 and hide screen1" that I'm calling before pushing concrete UIViewController. Now, I know that having a separate MVC for separate screen would be more cleared but I'm a little bit annoyed about the duplicate stuff, so I'm taking an action to split only if there are major differences. How do you deal with such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to have a separate MVC for every screen—that can get very messy! A controller can easily have multiple UIView outlets that you can hook up in IB and switch around as needed. Remember though, that MVC and other paradigms are a suggested design to make your life easier, not a law. You won't go to the 9th layer of programmer's hell for not using it—in the end, it's up to you. Use whatever makes sense for you and your app!

Comment: Having separate views as IBOutlets for each different screen of concrete MVC gives a lot of clarity when designing UI with IB. Thanks for brilliant idea, good luck.